# Popper: CSS "margin" styles cannot be used to apply padding between the popper and its reference element or boundary. react bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, popper.js

I am working on a react project using react-bootstrap and facing this warning when clicking on the dropdown menu.

Popper: CSS "margin" styles cannot be used to apply padding between the popper and its reference element or boundary. To replicate margin, use the `offset` modifier, as well as the `padding` option in the `preventOverflow` and `flip` modifiers.

```
<Dropdown alignRight className="dropdown m-0">
   <Dropdown.Toggle as={CustomToggle} />
   <Dropdown.Menu style={{ margin: 0 }}>
      <Dropdown.Item >edit</Dropdown.Item>
   </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: looks ok https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-goldwasser-1lxhm?file=/src/App.js - no errors on my side

Comment: Yeah, I see there is an issue with my custom classes. Thank you for your effort

Answer (score 12):

By adding style with margin the error message disappears `Dropdown.Menu style={{ margin: 0 }}`

Comment: Some explanation would benefit everyone applying this "fix" ...

Answer (score 1):

I observed this error message while using the MUI Autocomplete control (which also uses Popper), while doing server-side data retrieval.

I am struggling to narrow down exactly what combination of props causes the warning, but I do know that removing `disablePortal` has removed the warning. It also doesn't seem to affect my use case (the [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/) merely suggests using `disablePortal` to workaround an accessibility issue on iOS).

Here's an example from my code:

```
<Autocomplete
      inputValue={acInputValue}
      onInputChange={(e_, newValue, reason) => {
        setMode(reason);
        setAcInputValue(newValue);
      }}
      value={firstMatchingOption}
      onChange={(e_, selectedValue) => {
        onChange({
          target: {
            name,
            value: selectedValue,
          },
        });
      }}
      // disablePortal // removing this stops the warning
      options={options}
      filterOptions={(x) => x} // for server-side filtering
      getOptionLabel={lookupLabel}
      // use mongo ids because my labels are not unique
      renderOption={(props, id) => (
        <li {...props} key={id}>
          {lookupLabel(id)}
        </li>
      )}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label={isProgressing ? 'loading...' : label} />
      )}
    />
```